# Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.sendgrid.net:587

Tags: laravel, sendgrid-api-v3

Some eamils sent successfully at start. But After that I face same issue again and again.
That's my .env variables.
Mail User Name: "apikey"
Mail Password: "Secrect API key"
Mail Host: "smtp.sendgrid.net"
Mail Encryption: "tls"
Mail Port: "587"
Mail Mailer: "smtp"
Mail From Name: "Demo"
Mail Mailer: "Demo@demo.com"

I have been apply this solution but not working.
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl